# Separating points

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Assume $A$ is a closed subalgebra of $C(S)$, the space of continuous complex functions on compact Hausdorff space $S$.  Assume $A$ separates point on $S$ and and if $f \in A$ then $\bar{f}\in A$.  Assume for each $p\in S$, there exists an $f\in A$ such that $f(p)\neq 0$.

Why do the functions $f+\bar{f}$ separate points on $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \neq y \in S$ there is $f \in A$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$, so either $\operatorname{Re}f(x) \neq \operatorname{Re}f(y)$ or $\operatorname{Im}f(x) \neq \operatorname{Im}f(y)$. But $2\operatorname{Re}f = f + \overline{f}$ and $2\operatorname{Im}f = (-if) + \overline{(-if)}$ have the form you want.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are incorrect unless I don't understand your last sentence. Yes if the real parts are unequal we are done but if the complex parts are unequal then we we add the two and the imaginary parts go away.

Comment: Actually you are correct I misread your last sentence.  You may want to word it slightly better.